# Shell Script , curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host in

Tags: shell, curl

I am writing my first shell script which I want to use to check the output of a server. Unfortunately, I am having trouble running the `curl` command.

**Script:**

```
# first shell script
#
clear;
echo "Knowledge is power";

r=$(( $RANDOM % 10 + 40 ));
echo $r;

test = $(curl \"google.com\");
echo $test
```

**Output:**

```
Knowledge is power
44

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '"google.com"'

backuppc@backup-pc:/media/scripts$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to escape the double quotes (or, in this case, to even have quotes at all);  try it without putting a backslash before them:

```
test=$(curl "google.com")
```

Also note that you cannot have spaces before or after the equals sign in variable assignment.